# How to disable Win key while gaming so Windows does not kill me?

Tags: windows, gaming

Is there a way to disable the WIN-keys, while I'm in a full-screen game?

Comment: Some modern gaming keyboards have a "game mode" which disables the Windows key as well. HyperX use Fn + F12 (F12 has a "G" in crosshairs on this key) so if you have a gaming keyboard it might be worth checking your manual for this option.

Comment: Expanding on @Mokubai's comment: `Fn` + `F6` or `Fn` + `Windows key` may work. I couldn't find good documentation on how widely it may work, some sources say Alienware & Dell gaming laptops only, but Dell says it's a Windows feature, as do some other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install AutoHotKey
- Edit to add your games and run this script `DisableWinKey.ahk`

```
#If WinActive("Last Epoch") or WinActive("Path of Exile") or WinActive("Starcraft II")

LWIN::
RWIN::
```

Alternatively look for a way to detect fullscreen apps in [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), maybe like this [detect-fullscreen question](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/38882-detect-fullscreen-application/)

Comment: Hi Arberg, it looks like you accidentally clicked the Header button in the editor. Please check the code   `#If WinActive("Last Epoch") or WinActive("Path of Exile") or WinActive("Starcraft II")## Heading ##`

Answer (score 3):

Try WinKill: https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/winkill.html

Sits in the systray, click the icon to toggle the windows key on/off.

You could also consider getting yourself a gaming keyboard. Some of these (for example in the Logitech G series) come with physical switches to turn the windows key on/off. Saves alt-tabbing out of the game to do this.

Comment: I didn't know there were such gaming keyboards, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, in my opinion, is to get an older keyboard WITHOUT windows keys (something from before WIN95 era) and a USB to PS2 adapter.